# Как задать регулярное выражение в router.get()

Tags: регулярные-выражения, node.js, express

Вот код, который работает и процветает, но попытки добавить регулярное выражение, ни к чему не приводят...

```js
router.get('/id', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    res.render('profile',{ title: 'Профиль' });
});
```

Я пробую в самый разных комбинациях, но работает только эта...

```js
router.get('/:id([0-9]{3,8})', function(...)
```

Так как пример взят из интернета. Когда самы птаюсь напистаь что-то в духе:

```js
router.get('/:id(/./)', function(...)
router.get('/:id/./', function(...)
router.get('/:id/(.)/', function(...)
```

Никакой из этих вариантов не работает, почему? Как правильно вставить регулярное выражение в данном случае?

Comment: Какие адреса необходимо обрабатывать ?

Comment: @ReinRaus любая буква или число от 3 до 10 символов

Comment: Адрес это нечто другое. Взгляните в окно своего браузера- там написан адрес, к примеру, этой страницы.